# Django REST framework POST request with dynamic field inside a nested field using Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to send a POST request in an API with the two different data samples as below.

The POST data has different schema on options key depending on the choice key. The keys inside options key differ except few common fields.

I want to validate the fields with the help of Serializer too. How can I solve this?

Case 1

```json
{
  "name": "name1",
  "options": {
    "choice": "choice1",
    "common_option1": value1,
    "common_option2": value2,
    "choice1_option1": value3,
    "choice1_option2": value4
  }
}
```

Case 2

```json
{
  "name": "name2",
  "options": {
    "choice": "choice2",
    "common_option1": value5,
    "choice2_option1": value6,
    "choice2_option2": value7,
    "choice2_option3": value8
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe define all possible options in the serializer, and validate it in the serializer as well depending on name?

Comment: If I let all the possible options to go into, can I validate that the only appropriate options were sent for the selected choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `update` method on you serializer:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
        
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        
        # unpack options from initial data:
        options = self.initial_data['options']

        # option 1:
        if options['choice'] == 'choice1':
            # do something

        # option 2:
        elif options['choice'] == 'choice2':
            # do something else
        
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```